# Is there risk of unavailable sources in composer-based project?

Tags: php, deployment, dependencies, dependency-management, composer-php

When putting together a PHP project with composer, on installation / deployment, composer would fetch the dependencies usually from their original sources.

This could lead to problems when deploying, when a source (maybe only temporarily) becomes unavailable.

Is there any included mechanism to keep at least the current, stable versions of the dependencies some where to be always able to deploy the current version to other instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Broker looks like a tool which could serve as a proxy to keep files, and is now integrated into Satis (see https://github.com/researchgate/broker)

> broker is a full repository proxy for composer. It takes a composer file, downloads all 
>   requirements and all dependencies, and then publishes a new repository with all these 
>   packages. Instead of packagist or satis, all packages, including dist and source files will > be served directly by broker.
>
> Note: this project is not actively maintained anymore. Since satis supports a similar 
>   functionality now, you should use satis instead.

Answer (score 1):

Right now there is no one click solution for this, but I plan to work on something soon that will give you more reliability.

Comment: How would that look like? Are there already drafts or something like that?